# How can I express this result as a single sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm working on a problem where I want to express my final result as the sum of many components. The expression on which I am stuck is this:

$$
Q =\mathrm{sign}\left(\frac{Q(2 \pi) - Q(f_{k})}{2}\right) \left[Q\left(2 \pi\right) - Q\left(f_{k}\right)\right] + \sum_{j=2}^{k} \mathrm{sign}\left(\frac{Q(f_j) - Q(f_{j-1})}{2}\right) \left[Q\left(f_j\right) - Q\left(f_{j-1}\right)\right] + \mathrm{sign}\left(\frac{Q(f_1) - Q(0)}{2}\right) \left[Q\left(f_1\right) - Q\left(0\right)\right]
$$
In this problem, $Q(f)$ is an integral of another function $I(f)$. The $f_j$, $f_{j-1}, ...$ are the inflection points of $Q(f)$. However in this problem the points $0$ and $2 \pi$ are not necessarily the points of inflection of $Q(f)$, some times it is, but not always. However, I always need to take into account those terms.
I'd like to make it more beautiful and compact, just like the summation in the second term on the right-hand side.

I've been trying to simplify it for three days and have not been able to do it. Please, help me internet people from Math Stack Exchange!

Comment: could you share what youve tried? if youve been trying for 3 days you may have come across some of the pit falls we are likely to see. also if you showed us the things you have tried we can further help you and others that come later that think like you in how to come to such an answer.

Comment: The best I could do is:
$$Q =\sum_{k=1}^{N+1} \mathrm{sign}\left(\frac{Q(f_k) - Q(f_{k-1})}{2}\right) \left[Q\left(f_k\right) - Q\left(f_{k-1}\right)\right]$$
Where $f_0=0$ and $f_{N+1}=2 \pi$.
I'm no mathematician, I'm an engineering, please don't judge my lack of originality.

Comment: I don't like the above formula, because in the paper I explicitly state that $f_k$'s are the inflection points of $Q(f)$. And put the conditions $f_0=0$ and $f_{N+1}=2 \pi$ are not necessarily inflection points of $Q(f)$. So I think I'm abusing the notation